# Android how to change a TimerTask interval after shcedule?

Tags: java, android

```
timerUploadTime = new Timer();
timerUploadTimeTask = new TimerTask() {
   @Override public void run() {
      mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
         public void run() {
             ...
          }
      }
    });
 }
 };

timerUploadTime.schedule(timerUploadTimeTask, 1, Integer.parseInt(Utils.loadStringValue(mycontext, "refresh")));
```

I'd like to change my timer's interval, in an other code segment. Is there a way to do that? 
I dont want to retiming my code, i would like to add a new "period" interval.

How can I do that after schedule?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can't**. You'll have to cancel the current task and reschedule.

Comment: any other ways to do this? or alternatives?

Comment: @lacas, No, none that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3):

You should cancel the timer before you can set a new schedule to it.

```
timerTask.cancel();
timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
timer.schedule(timerTask, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it happen is to schedule your Timer for running every second, and inside your timer runnable, increase a counter by one every second, then you can add if statement to check your counter mod by your desired counter variable (in terms of seconds) to return without doing anything

```
timerCounter++;
if((timerCounter%desiredCounter)!=0){
 return;
}
```