# Java Android App Random Color and Timer

Tags: java, android, random, colors, timer

I have an app that has a square that moves around the screen every 1.5 seconds and every time you click it you get a point. I'm trying to make it where every you click the square the color changes to a random color. Also, I want to have an option under settings for a harder mode where the square moves every .7 seconds.

Here is my draw method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
Paint dotPaint = new Paint();       
    canvas.drawRect(dotX, dotY, dotX + 60, dotY + 60, dotPaint);
dotPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
dotPaint.setTextSize(60); 
    canvas.drawText("Score: " + score, 20, 60, dotPaint);
```

and here is my onTouch method:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (detectHit( (int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY() )) {
    score++;
    invalidate();
}
        return false;
```

I'm not too sure how to go about making the color of the square change every click.

```
Also, here is my menu items:

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle menu item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item1:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            quit();
            return true;
        case R.id.item3:
            harder();
            return true;
        default: 
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

and my harder method:
public void harder(){
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 700);
}
```

Comment: so, i think i covered most of your questions. But you will still have to deal with moving it faster. I assume timer is running some task, that forces the ui to redraw every 1.5 seconds atm. so changing that to .700 should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Well just a suggestion, change your detectHits() Method from (int ... , int ...) to (MotionEvent ...) shortens the call.

For a Random color you will habe to generate one programmatically.
There is this `Color.rgb(int red, int green, int blue)` Method, which you might want to use.

So now what you do is, you generate Random ints to generate a Color, like this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Color rndCol = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(254), rnd.nextInt(254), rnd.nextInt(254));
```

now you will have ti apply that color.
First of all its discourage to allocate objects during onDraw, so move that allocation of Paint to onCreate/onResume and make it a field in the process. Then you will have to adapt your onTouchMethod like this.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (detectHit(event)) {
    changeColor();
    score++;
    invalidate();
}
return false;

private void changeColor(){
   Random rnd = new Random();
   Color rndCol = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(254), rnd.nextInt(254), rnd.nextInt(254));
   dotPaint.setColor(rndCol); // this should be a field by now and accessible from within this method
}
```

in the matter of changing the speed from 1.5 to 0.7 make the timing a field in the class, and at a certain point reduce the this value to reduce the timer.

As you didnt show how you are currently moving the square every 1.5 seconds i cant adapt the code for you.

Comment: Okay I understand the random color now except it's saying that dotPaint can't be resolved..

Comment: And here is how I'm moving the square every 1.5 seconds.                   timer = new Timer();
task = new DotSmasherTimerTask(canvas);
timer.schedule(task, 0, 1500);

Comment: yes it cant be resolved, because i guess you didnt read the text :)
you will have to make that dotPaint a field in your class, or you cant access it at that point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257449/android-how-to-change-a-timertask-interval-after-shcedule - this should show you how to change the timings

Comment: Sorry haha yea I figured that out right after I posted that comment.

Comment: Okay so for the random color, every time I run the app it crashes. Here is what my logcats say: 01-22 19:01:05.822: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1161):  at com.dotsmasherdg.DotSmasherCanvas.changeColor(DotSmasherCanvas.java:92)

Comment: saying I have a NullPointerException

Comment: DotSmasherCanvas a class fo yours?